# Regular Expressions Transport Rules Detect asterick '*****SPAM'

Tags: exchange

I am having trouble understanding how I can detect any emails with that have "*****SPAM" in the subject line. Based on the documentation regular expressions https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997187(v=exchg.141).aspx
I have used a "^" before this string and tried using a "\" escaping character . Any advice how I can detect this? (The 5 asterisk are throwing me off).  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect 5 asterisks at the begining of the string:

```
^\*\*\*\*\*
```

To detect the string "*****SPAM" anywhere in the string, use this:

```
\*\*\*\*\*SPAM
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately it still isn't working for my transport rule in exchange. I am using: "when the subject field contains" option for the transport rule.(This is where I put this regular expression) Then  for my action I have it raise the spam confidence level so it is sent to users junk-email folder. It will work great if I put an exact subject line from an email, but attempting searching for this partial string doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Are you adding a "when the Subject field contains specific words" rule, or a "when the Subject field matches text patterns" rule? Regular expressions are only used in the "pattern" rules. If your using the other type, just put in *****SPAM

Comment: That was it! I needed to switch transport rule to "when the subject field matches". Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Transport rule predicates: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638183(v=exchg.160).aspx   For REGEX, you want to use the predicate  `SubjectMatchesPatterns`